# Samsung NP700Z5B-S01UB reboots during Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, samsung, usb-installation

I've tried installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 and 23.04 on a Samsung NP700Z5B-S01UB notebook about 6 times and got the very same problem everytime. After booting from USB, creating a new ext4 (mounted on /) partition and starting installation, the notebook just reboots with no error message and Windows 7 starts.

I've downloaded ubuntu iso from official website and I've made the USB Boot using balenaEtcher.
I've found some similar problems here, but not the same problem as mine ([Ubuntu on Samsung NP700Z5B - no Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115312/ubuntu-on-samsung-np700z5b-no-grub)).

The notebooks specs can be found here: https://gadgetaz.com/Laptop/Samsung_NP700Z5B-S01UB--5122

Does anybody knows how to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Can you boot your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode? Does it work?